# camel not knowing amount of endpoints in loadbalancer

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to loadbalance in a camel route without knowing the amount of endpoints before runtime?

As an example, certain incoming requests has to loadbalance over certain servers and the servers are configured.

using `.loadBalance().failover().to()` how can I dynamically set the amount of `to()` endpoints?

I have tried it with toD() and sending a string of comma seperated endpoints but it sends the request to all servers and does not loadbalance.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to use the Java DSL.

```
//Setup dynamic list of endpoints
List<String> toDefs = new ArrayList<String>();
toDefs.add("mock:a");
toDefs.add("mock:b");

//We need to modify the definition, so get the reference
LoadBalanceDefinition loadBalanceDefinition = 
  from("dirct:start")
    .loadBalance()
    .failover();

//Dynamically add the list of endpoints         
for (String toDef: toDefs){
  loadBalanceDefinition = loadBalanceDefinition.to(toDef);
}

//Finalize the route            
loadBalanceDefinition.to("direct:end");
```

Comment: I have tried this, however every inbound request has different endpoints, as an example request A has endpoint A and B while Request B has endpoint A and C. Once this route is started the toDefs cannot be changed without restarting the route. Is starting and stopping a route viable? this is on CXFRS inbound request.

Comment: A stop/start is pretty high cost. It sounds like you may be stuck doing this work manually.